# How to run 2 tasks from command line with gradlew

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

Given a gradle wrapper (gradlew) from Android Studio distribution, is it possible to run two tasks with it within one command invocation? For example, right now I have to do the following:

```
./gradlew task1
./gradlew task2
```

Is it possible to invoke `./gradlew` only once, while executing both tasks?

Please note, that I do not want to make `task2` depend on `task1`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
./gradlew task1 task2
```

Such as:

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how i clean, run tests and build releases for all variants for a module.

```
./gradlew clean modulename:connectedAndroidTest assembleRelease
```